App crashes when trying to use a pre-populated room database due to difference between the schemes
I'm trying to make a small app for a project and decided to use a pre-populated database however i keep getting an error that says that the Expected and Found schemes are different, but i don't know what i need to do since the table names are the same, the type and name of the fields are also the same and they should be in the same position.
//Entity.kt
@Entity(tableName = "Book")
data class Book(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo val idImage: Int,
    @ColumnInfo val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo val author: String,
    @ColumnInfo val categories: String,
    @ColumnInfo val rating: Double,
    @ColumnInfo val discount: Int,
    @ColumnInfo val price: Double,
    @ColumnInfo val synopsis: String
)

//DAOs.kt
@Dao
interface BooksDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM book")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<Book>>
}

//the table in the pre-populated database
CREATE TABLE "Book" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "idImage"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "title" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "author"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "category"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "rating"    REAL NOT NULL,
    "discount"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "price" REAL NOT NULL,
    "synopsis"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

//BooksDatabase.kt
@Database(entities = [Book::class], version = 1, exportSchema = true)
abstract class BooksDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun booksDao(): BooksDao
}

//BooksRepository.kt
class BooksRepository(private val booksDao: BooksDao) {
    val books: Flow<List<Book>> = booksDao.getAll()
}

//BooksViewModel.kt
data class BooksState(val books: List<Book>)

class BooksViewModel(private val repository: BooksRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val state = repository.books.map { BooksState(books = it) }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
        initialValue = BooksState(emptyList())
    )
}

//AppModule.kt
val AppModule = module {

    single {
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            get(),
            BooksDatabase::class.java,
            "books-list"
        ).createFromAsset("database/bookDatabase.db").build()
    }
    single { BooksRepository(get<BooksDatabase>().booksDao()) }
    viewModel { BooksViewModel(get()) }

}

//LibraryApplication.kt
class LibraryApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@LibraryApplication)
            modules(AppModule)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun StoreScreen() {
    val booksVM = koinViewModel<BooksViewModel>()
    val bookState by booksVM.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
}


When i go to the storeScreen the app immediately crashes and it gives me this error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                  Process: com.example.digitallibrary, PID: 7611                                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: Book(com.example.digitallibrary.data.database.Book).
Expected: TableInfo{name='Book', columns={author=Column{name='author', type='TEXT',affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}, price=Column{name='price',type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true,primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'},rating=Column{me='rating', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true,primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}, discount=Column{name='discount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'},idImage=Column{name='idImage', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true,primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, id=Column{name='id',type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1,defaultValue='undefined'}, categories=Column{name='categories',type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}, synopsis=Column{name='synopsis', type='TEXT',affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT',affinity='2', notNull=true,primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices[]}
    Found:TableInfo{name='Book', columns={id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, idImage=Column{name='idImage', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT',affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}, author=Column{name='author', type='TEXT',affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}, category=Column{name='category', type='TEXT',affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}, rating=Column{name='rating', type='REAL',affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}, discount=Column{name='discount', type='INTEGER',affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}, price=Column{name='price', type='REAL',affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}, synopsis=Column{name='synopsis', type='TEXT',affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

I tried checking online but all the solutions are either really bare bone or just suggest to add the .createFromAsset() to the .build()

"the app immediately crashes" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash. If you do not understand the stack trace, edit your question to include it and the source code that it mentions as part of your [mcve].

OK i checked the log and it says that the problem is that the found scheme is different than the one it expected.

what exactly did it highlight?

You will need to update your asset with a database whose schema matches what your code expects. Alternatively, update your code to match the schema of the database. Either way, those two need to agree on the columns and the column details (e.g., types).

but how do i match them? since all of the rows are in the same places and the types should all match, what else do i need to do?

@nm16pc: You will need to compare the two lines in the error message (Expected and Found) and identify what is different, then make changes to address that difference.

If you modified your database entities You have to update the version number of the database
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)

Or uninstall the app from the emulator or your device and relaunch the app.

uninstalling will clear all the data

Ok i think solved it, i just named one of the fields(ie category) in the Entity wrong(it was categories in there)
